# Calling specific dates and values in stock prices

Tags: pandas, stocks

How do i call data for the dates and values for any shares?

Example: I want to call the stock price and date for apple shares only for dec 2016, dec 2017.

Here is what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like

import pandas_datareader.data as web

import numpy as np

from matplotlib import style

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2013,10,1)

end= dt.datetime(2018,4,30)

AAPL_data=[]

AAPL= web.DataReader('AAPL','iex', start, end)
AAPL_data.append(AAPL)
```

Comment: Is this actually a Pandas question? Please add more details so we can help you.

Comment: hi Josh, yes its a Pandas question.

Comment: import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

start = dt.datetime(2013,10,1)
end= dt.datetime(2018,4,30)

AAPL_data=[]

AAPL= web.DataReader('AAPL','iex', start, end)
AAPL_data.append(AAPL)

Comment: sorry kinda new here..

Comment: Don't worry - we were all new once. Thanks for sharing the code, that's much better. Could you put it into your question using the edit function, and format it with `code` tags?

Comment: got it! hope you'll be able to help. Thanks Josh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AAPL.loc['2016-12-01':'2016-12-31']

AAPL.loc['2017-12-01':'2017-12-31']
```

both work for me, for December '16/'17 data respectively. Pandas datetime indexing is very flexible and intuitive, see more examples [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

Incidentally, if you're using the new release of pandas-datareader (0.7.0), you no longer need to insert `pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like`.